# How to make toggle button for google app engine

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, google-app-engine, toggle

I'm trying to make a toggle button for adding friends (like in snapchat).

Right now my html uses checkboxes and submit buttons

```
{% for u in u %}
    {{u.name}} <input type="checkbox" name = "checkbox" value="{{u.name}}">
{% endfor %}
```

where if the checkbox is submitted, the user is added as a friend. I looked in the jQuery docs and the only toggle functions are hide and show and manipulating animations.

Help?

Edit:
I tried inserting AJAX into a test file that had foo (bare with my beginner code), so that when I check the checkbox the AJAX would send "foo" through the post method to the server...but nothing happens when I check the checkbox.

```
<form method = "post">
Foo <input type="checkbox" onclick = "toggle();" class = "login_button" name = "checkbox" value="Foo">
</form>

<script  src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function toggle() {
        var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {

        //when server is ready
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
          var value = document.getElementsByName('checkbox')
        }
      }
      xmlhttp.open("POST","/test",true);
      xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
      xmlhttp.send("value=" + value);

    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open("GET", "/test", true);
    xmlHttp.addEventListener("load", ajaxCallback, false);
    xmlHttp.send(null);

    function ajaxCallback(event){
    alert( "Your file contains the text: " + event.target.responseText );
    }
    }


  </script>
</form>
```

When I want to make a new instance of TestModel with "foo" as the value, so I have

```
class TestModel(db.Model):
    value = db.StringProperty(required = True)
```

and

```
class Test(Handler):
    def get(self):
        if self.user:
            values = TestModel.all()
            self.render("ajaxtest.html", values = values)
        else:
            self.redirect("/signup")

    def post(self):
        value = self.request.get('checkbox')
        if value:
            value = TestModel(value = value)
            value.put()
            self.write("success")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question has very little to do with `Google App Engine`. What you probably want is, from looking at your code snippet, a HTML template construct to have a have a checkbox that indicates that somebody is a friend.

Something like (taking your snippet as a departure, untested):

```
{% for u in u %}
    {{ u.name }}
    {% if u.is_friend() %}
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-{{ u.pk }}" checked="checked">
    {% else %}
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-{{ u.pk }}">
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

The above is just one possible solution. There's a myriad of possibilities for a working solution, but you will have to be more specific in your question.

Obviously you will have to do further processing once the form is submitted to check whether the user friended or unfriended any of the instances you name "u" but I leave that to your own imagination.

Comment: With this the user still has to click the submit button for anything to happen; how would I make the page immediately send a changed checkbox's state to the server once a checkbox is toggled?

Comment: Use jQuery to submit an AJAX post when the user clicks a checkbox with the value of the checkbox (true or false, friend or unfriend). The AJAX call links to a view (guessing you're working with Django here) that updates the model object represented by your "u". There's plenty of samples available from the jQuery site.